# How can we retrieve users schedule time using Opsgenia API?

Tags: rest, export-to-excel, opsgenie

I am working on a project which requires getting on-call data from multiple teams in Opsgenia to be written into an Excel file I have managed to get the name day date and team name however I can't seem to find a way to get the person on call's start time and end time can anyone help? I have gone through the documentation it gives dates for the entire rotation not individual person.